# number and size of eigenvectors in PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, covariance-matrix, intuition, eigenvalues

As I understand, the size of eigenvector produced in PCA should be min{n,N}, where N=number of samples and n=dimension of each sample (Right?). However, I have seen in couple of cases that this size is max{n,N}, not min. Why?

And the next relevant question is,

Are number of produced eigenvectors equal to their size (I know we pick the first couple of them in PCA, but I am talking about the produced ones)? It should be, as the number of eigenvectors is always equal to size of each eigenvector.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by the "size" of an eigenvector?  Would that be its *dimension*?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to compute PCA is by using eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix of the data matrix $\underset{N \times n}{X}$, which is $\underset{n\times n}{X^TX}$ if $X$ is mean-centralized. Since we generally have $n \ll N$, it's computationally much faster to compute the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix $X^TX$. It outputs $n$ eigenvalues and an $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors as columns where the dimension of each eigenvector is $n \times 1$.

But, sometimes we have $N \ll n$ (e.g., for patient-genes data), then it's computationally very expensive to do the eigen-decomposition of $X^TX$, instead it's easier to do the eigen-decomposition of $\underset{N \times N}{XX^T}$, since both have same eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $X^TX$ can be computed easily from the eigenvectors of $XX^T$.

For example, let $XX^T$ has eigenvalue $λ$ and the corresponding eigenvector $v$, then we have,

$XX^Tv=λv⟹(X^TX)(X^Tv)=λ(X^Tv)$, i.e, $\underset{n\times N}{X^T}.\underset{N \times 1}{v}$ is an eigenvector of $X^TX$ (upto normalization).

Comment: Re your first line: AFAIK PCA is usually done by SVD of $X$ itself, because analyzing $X^\prime X$ loses about half the precision in the numbers.

Comment: @whuber true, for numeric precision SVD is favored I think as opposed to eigen-decomposition (which is another way to compute principal components), e.g., `prcomp` vs `princomp` implementations in `R`, but I think OP wanted to know about the dimension of the eigenvectors (as opposed to the left / right singular vectors), which could be explained better with the eigen-decomposition approach I guess, is not it?

Comment: Hi Sandipan Dey, and thank for your answer.

I am still confused because the eigenvalues of a matrix with n with a lower rank m will have only m non-zero eigenvalues, that means, in term of svd, only m singular values are non-zero. So for me it still means that we have min{n,N} eigenvectors, and not more. Right?

Comment: @Maria for PCA with SVD we have $\underset{N\times n}{X}=\underset{N\times N}{U}\underset{N\times n}{\Sigma}\underset{n\times n}{V^T}$,  clearly the $\min(n,N)$ non-zero singular values, the other singular values being zero, $N$ left singular vectors (eigenvectors of $XX^T$) and $n$ right singular vectors (eigenvectors of $X^TX$)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.